# @Slf4j from private to public

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, lombok

I know `lombok.extern.slf4j`'s `@Slf4j` annotation creates `private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogExample.class);`

But can I make this public somehow? Making the annotation to create: `public static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogExample.class);`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why would you want this?

Comment: Copy the logger into a protected variable.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, I want to use annotation beacuse I don't want to import Logger and LoggerFactory classes, and then make a variable. Or I just don't get it what did you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Lombok documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/log), this doesn't seem possible. You could declare your own logger, but I highly doubt that you need to make the logger public and accessible from some other class. Usually you create a different logger instance for each class. Do you have a reason why you want it to be public?

Comment: My test classes are extended from one base class, until now it was enough to declare the log variable and the other classes used the base one. But now they cannot reach it, because annotation makes it private.

Comment: If you have only one (or few) base classes, you could just explicitly declare it as protected and be done with it. I would still encourage you to refactor your code to have different loggers, as this would allow you to better control the kind of messages which get logged, like settings custom rules for each package or for  application vs test classes.

Comment: What should I declare protected?

Comment: The explicit logger instance